# Infinite loop in.readTypedList method android parcelable

Tags: android, arraylist, out-of-memory, infinite-loop, parcelable

i've some problem experiencing 2-depth Parcelable. I have 3 classes, including themselves as this schema :

```
Serie
    List<Qcm>
        List<Proposition>
```

All of them are implementing Parcelable interface from `android.os.Parcelable`.
The problem occurs when i try to pass a `Serie` object to another activity with `putExtra()`, there is a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` when i use `getParcelable()` from the Activity where i want to retreive my `Serie` object.

The normal behavior should be as below :

- One Serie contains a variable number of Qcm (N Qcm)
- One Qcm contains 5 Proposition(s)

The fact is when I log `createFromParcel()` calls, I see that `createFromParcel()` from Proposition is called 5 times for the first loop iteration, then never stop calling at the next iteration.

My stacktrace :

```
04-18 15:19:19.565  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Qcm.createFromParcel﹕ qcm cree
04-18 15:19:19.570  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.570  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.570  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.570  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.575  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.575  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Qcm.createFromParcel﹕ qcm cree
04-18 15:19:19.575  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.575  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.580  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.580  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.580  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.580  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.580  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.585  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.585  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.585  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.585  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.590  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.590  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.590  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.590  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.590  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.600  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
04-18 15:19:19.600  14089-14089/com.examed.maprepaquotidienne D/MPQ.Proposition.createFromParcel﹕ proposition cree
```

---

**Serie.java**

```
package examed.lib.classes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import examed.lib.DAO.FrequenceDAO;
import examed.lib.DAO.SerieDAO;
import examed.lib.DAO.UEDAO;
import examed.lib.workers.APIHelper;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Serie implements Parcelable
{

    private int id;
    private UE uniteEnseignement;
    private Frequence frq;
    private int type;
    private String authorFirstname, authorName, authorAvatar;
    private Date datePublication;
    private int anneeSerie, nbQcm, order;
    private String title, subtitle;
    private String beforeText;
    private String afterText;
    private List<Qcm> listeQcm = new ArrayList<Qcm>();
    private float chanceCoeff;
    private boolean enCreation;
    private boolean publiee;
    private Date dateValidationPubliee;
    private Date dateFinCreation;
    private int maxTime;
    private int statut;

    public Serie(Parcel in) throws ParseException, NullPointerException
    {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        this.id = in.readInt();
        this.uniteEnseignement = in.readParcelable(UE.class.getClassLoader());
        this.frq = in.readParcelable(Frequence.class.getClassLoader());
        this.type = in.readInt();
        this.authorFirstname = in.readString();
        this.authorName = in.readString();
        this.authorAvatar = in.readString();
        this.datePublication = dateFormat.parse(in.readString());
        this.anneeSerie = in.readInt();
        this.nbQcm = in.readInt();
        this.order = in.readInt();
        this.title = in.readString();
        this.subtitle = in.readString();
        this.beforeText = in.readString();
        this.afterText = in.readString();
        in.readTypedList(this.listeQcm, Qcm.CREATOR);
        this.chanceCoeff = in.readFloat();
        this.enCreation = (in.readInt() > 0);
        this.publiee = (in.readInt() > 0);
        this.dateValidationPubliee = dateFormat.parse(in.readString());
        this.dateFinCreation = dateFormat.parse(in.readString());
        this.maxTime = in.readInt();
        this.statut = in.readInt();
    }

    [...]

    // region [PARCELABLE]

    @Override
    public int describeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        dest.writeInt(this.id);
        dest.writeParcelable(this.uniteEnseignement, flags);
        dest.writeParcelable(this.frq, flags);
        dest.writeInt(this.type);
        dest.writeString(this.authorFirstname);
        dest.writeString(this.authorName);
        dest.writeString(this.authorAvatar);
        dest.writeString(this.getDatePublication());
        dest.writeInt(this.anneeSerie);
        dest.writeInt(this.nbQcm);
        dest.writeInt(this.order);
        dest.writeString(this.title);
        dest.writeString(this.subtitle);
        dest.writeString(this.beforeText);
        dest.writeString(this.afterText);
        dest.writeTypedList(this.listeQcm);
        dest.writeDouble((double) this.chanceCoeff);
        dest.writeInt((this.enCreation) ? 1 : 0);
        dest.writeInt((this.publiee) ? 1 : 0);
        dest.writeString(this.getDateValidationPubliee());
        dest.writeString(this.getDateFinCreation());
        dest.writeInt(this.maxTime);
        dest.writeInt(this.statut);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Serie> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Serie>()
    {
        @Override
        public Serie createFromParcel(Parcel source)
        {
            Serie serie = null;

            try {
                serie = new Serie(source);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return serie;
        }

        @Override
        public Serie[] newArray(int size)
        {
            return new Serie[size];
        }
    };

    // endregion
}
```

**Qcm.java**

```
package examed.lib.classes;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import examed.lib.workers.APIHelper;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Qcm implements Parcelable
{
    private int id;
    private String question;
    private int typeNotation;
    private List<Proposition> propositions = new ArrayList<Proposition>();
    private Date dateCreation;
    private Date dateUpdate;
    private int typeChapitre;
    private boolean validee;
    private int annee;
    private boolean origineAnnale;
    private float coeff;
    private int duree;

    public static String FIELD_QCM_ID = "QCMID";
    public static String FIELD_QCM_QUESTION = "Question";
    public static String FIELD_QCM_TYPE_NOTATION_ID = "TypeNotationID";
    public static String FIELD_QCM_DATE_CREATION = "DateCreation";
    public static String FIELD_QCM_DATE_MODIF = "DateUpdate";
    public static String FIELD_QCM_TYPE_CHAPITRE = "TypeChapitreID";
    public static String FIELD_QCM_VALIDEE = "Validee";
    public static String FIELD_QCM_ANNEE = "Annee";
    public static String FIELD_QCM_ORIGINE_ANNALE = "OrigineAnnale";
    public static String FIELD_QCM_COEFF = "coef";
    public static String FIELD_QCM_DUREE = "dureeQCM";


    public Qcm(Parcel in) throws ParseException
    {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        this.id = in.readInt();
        this.question = in.readString();
        this.typeNotation = in.readInt();
        in.readTypedList(this.propositions, Proposition.CREATOR);
        this.dateCreation = dateFormat.parse(in.readString());
        this.dateUpdate = dateFormat.parse(in.readString());
        this.typeChapitre = in.readInt();
        this.validee = (in.readInt() > 0);
        this.annee = in.readInt();
        this.origineAnnale = (in.readInt() > 0);
        this.coeff = in.readFloat();
        this.duree = in.readInt();
    }

    // region [PARCELABLE]

    @Override
    public int describeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        dest.writeInt(this.id);
        dest.writeString(this.question);
        dest.writeInt(this.typeNotation);
        dest.writeTypedList(this.propositions);
        dest.writeString(dateFormat.format(this.dateCreation));
        dest.writeString(dateFormat.format(this.dateUpdate));
        dest.writeInt(this.typeChapitre);
        dest.writeInt((this.validee) ? 1 : 0);
        dest.writeInt(this.annee);
        dest.writeInt((this.origineAnnale) ? 1 : 0);
        dest.writeDouble((double)this.coeff);
        dest.writeInt(this.duree);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Qcm> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Qcm>()
    {
        @Override
        public Qcm createFromParcel(Parcel source)
        {
            Qcm qcm = null;
            APIHelper.log('d', "qcm cree");
            try {
                qcm = new Qcm(source);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return qcm;
        }

        @Override
        public Qcm[] newArray(int size)
        {
            return new Qcm[size];
        }
    };

    // endregion

}
```

**Proposition.java**

```
package examed.lib.classes;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import examed.lib.workers.APIHelper;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Proposition implements Parcelable
{

    private String content;
    private boolean toCheck;
    private String correction;


    public Proposition(Parcel in) throws ParseException
    {
        this.content = in.readString();
        this.toCheck = (in.readInt() > 0);
        this.correction = in.readString();
    }

    // region [PARCELABLE]

    @Override
    public int describeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        dest.writeString(this.content);
        dest.writeInt((this.toCheck) ? 1 : 0);
        dest.writeString(this.correction);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Proposition> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Proposition>()
    {
        @Override
        public Proposition createFromParcel(Parcel source)
        {
            Proposition proposition = null;

            try {
                proposition = new Proposition(source);
                APIHelper.log('d', "proposition cree");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return proposition;
        }

        @Override
        public Proposition[] newArray(int size)
        {
            return new Proposition[size];
        }
    };

    // endregion

}
```

**How I do the getParcelable in target Activity**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

if(intent.getExtras() != null)
{
    APIHelper.log('d', intent.getExtras().getParcelable("SELECTED_SERIE"));
    this.serie = intent.getExtras().getParcelable("SELECTED_SERIE");
    APIHelper.log('d', this.serie);
}
```

Let me know if you need sth else. I've been stucked on this for hours, I really don't get it.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Finally using a workaround solution, I've been using my JSON response, give it to the next activity with extras, and build my objects on the next activity.

That's a weird solution I think, but it seems that imbricated parcelable objects gets crasy with a too-long depth.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you have multi depth Parcelables you should try to create a unit test for it with lots of data to see if it doens't run out of memory or take to long to load. Simple List with primitive type shouldn't be to big of a problem but when the objects get more complex it can take a lot of memory and time.

Comment: I will try in the next release, thank you for your advice. 
Honestly, on my own I think that's not a problem of complex object, where the most used types on my objects are primitives.

However, I will try your advice.